# Error While using Macro to add google's first image link to excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the below Code to input Google's first images link in B1
for certain values in A1.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim imgElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim imgElement As HTMLImg
    Dim aElement As HTMLAnchorElement
    Dim N As Integer, I As Integer
    Dim Url As String, Url2 As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim m, sImageSearchString

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 1 To LastRow
        Url = "http://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(I, 1) & "&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&rnd=1"
        Set IE = New InternetExplorer

        With IE
            .Visible = False
            .Navigate Url 'sWebSiteURL

            Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
                'Do Until IE.document.readyState = "Complete": DoEvents: Loop

            Set HTMLdoc = .document

            Set imgElements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("IMG")

            N = 1
            For Each imgElement In imgElements
                If InStr(imgElement.src, sImageSearchString) Then
                    If imgElement.ParentNode.nodeName = "A" Then
                        Set aElement = imgElement.ParentNode

                        Url2 = imgElement.src
                        N = N + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            Cells(I, 2) = Url2

            IE.Quit
            Set IE = Nothing
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

however I'm receiving the below error, can you please advise?

I'm using Windows 10, Excel 365

[image]

Comment: Have you referenced `Microsoft Internet Controls`?

Answer (score 0):

**In VBA Menu - Tools - References - tick MS Internet Controls.**

Or

Using Late Binding

```
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir. I'm receiving a new error now. " object variable or with block variable not set " Can you please support?

Comment: Are you using Reference Method or Late binding?  On which line you get error?  Please explain.